# Can't find a way to get graphic tablet drivers working on mint

Tags: qt, qt5, tablet, linux-mint, pen

So i was trying to install the XP Pen Driver for my Deco 01 v2 graphics tablet on my Linux Mint 19.2 Tina when i came to encounter the following error:

> ./Pentablet_Driver: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by ./Pentablet_Driver)

I went on to install qt 5.10, still the same error. Others suggested to just change the path wth `sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf` which didn't change a thing.

Link to drivers:

> https://www.xp-pen.com/download-440.html

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for https://superuser.com than here, but anyway: Why you don't ask to the manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer has a page [describing how to set up their software on Linux with pictures](https://www.xp-pen.com/faq-56-210.html). However, when following them, you end up with a folder name somewhere along the line that has spaces in it, which causes issues.

So a modified set of instructions might look like this:

> 1. Connect your XP-Pen product to the computer.
> 2. Download the Linux Beta driver from [XP-Pen official website](https://www.xp-pen.com/).
> 3. When the download is complete, extract the compressed folder.
> 4. Rename the extracted folder to something without spaces.
> 5. Inside the renamed folder is another compressed folder which should be extracted.
> 6. Inside the final extracted folder, ensure "Pentablet_Driver.sh" has execution permissions by right clicking on it and going to "Properties->Permissions" and verifying that "Allow executing file as program" is checked.
> 7. Open the terminal. (CTRL+ALT+T)
> 8. Type "sudo ", then drag Pentablet_Driver.sh from the file browser onto the terminal.
> 9. Type the password to complete.

Comment: The new deb driver doesn't work, and Icannot find the good old one beta you mention anymore.

Comment: The old one is here: https://www.xp-pen.com.cn/download-36.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you write exactly

```
sudo ./Pentablet_Driver.sh
```

instead

```
sudo ./Pentablet_Driver
```

I had the same error until I noticed that I forgot to add `.sh` at the end.